# Is Google App Invites of any value if I want a user to access a web UX if the app is not installed?

Tags: android, ios, google-app-invites

I want to redirect the user to a semi-functional Website in the event that the mobile optimized app is not installed.

Are Google App Invites of any value if I want this enrollment flow?  I think the social media suggestions might be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

The google docs doesn't mention anything about what can be the Url. A Xamarin genius has used a Website url (http://motzcod.es/)  in his blogpost ( https://blog.xamarin.com/expand-your-apps-reach-with-googles-app-invites/ ).